# How to rewrite url in php?

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I have some question to ask about rewrite url in php.

1- www.test.com/index.php?name=123 to www.test.com/123

2- www.test.com/folder1/index.php?name=123 to www.test.com/folder1/123/index.php

Hereabout my coding on number 1 but i don't know how to rewrite number 2 combination with number 1:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond  %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond  %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule  ^(.*)$ index.php?usname=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*When you say "rewrite url in php", I assume that "in php" refers to the language of the application, not the rewrite/redirect method --- because your example code consists of Apache directives.*

The rules below will change URLs in the form test.com/folder1/index.php?name=123 into a "pretty" URL of the form test.com/folder1/123 (I removed the 'index.php' to be even more user-friendly).

1. Redirect the ugly query URL so users always see the "pretty" URL

   ```
   RewriteCond  %{QUERY_STRING} \bname=([^&]+)
   RewriteRule  ^/?folder1/index\.php$ /folder1/%1 [R=302]
   ```
2. Tell the server how to interpret the pretty URL

   ```
   RewriteRule  ^/?folder1/([^\/]+)(/index\.php)?$ /folder1/index.php?name=$1 [L]
   ```

**NOTE:** 
The first rule above uses a 302 (temporary) redirect, so your browser doesn't "memorize" the redirect rule while you're testing and tweaking them. If you care about SEO, change the `[R=302]` to `[R=301]`, which is a permanent redirect.

Comment: Is FollowSymLinks on (`Options +FollowSymLinks`)?  If so, when you use this rule: `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://google.com [R]` ... does it redirect you to Google?

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond  %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond  %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule  ^(.*)/([0-9]+)/index.php $1/index.php?name=$2 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule  ^(.*)$ index.php?usname=$1 [QSA,L]
```

The [L] instruction at the end of the rewrite rule means that if the rule match, it ends parsing the .htaccess.

So you have to place the rule before your rule ^(.*)$ wich handles every case

Comment: Dear number 2 is not working data/1234/index.php. original is data/index.php?name=1234