# How to remove and replace parameter from URL (GET)

Tags: php, html

So, let say that I have a link like this: **www.mywebsite/products/index.php?p=545**

What i want is to have this link : **www.mywebsite/products/nameofproduct**

So here as you see, my webiste is showing some products when I click in a picture of a specific product it redirect to the link above.
Do you have any idea how to do it ?

Here is the php code for the first link.

```
    <?php if(!empty($data["Format1"])) {$Stat = $pdo->query("SELECT * FROM ".$TB_PRODUCTS." WHERE ".$PAYS."='1' AND Code = '".$Format1."' "); while($dataF = $Stat->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){ ?>
<td width="81" align="center"><a href="index.php?p=<?php echo $dataF["NumId"]; ?>">
<?php if(file_exists($FormatA1)) {echo $Format01;} else {echo $Format00;}?>
</a></td><?php }} else {echo '';} ?>
```

Comment: it's a mod rewrite.

Comment: using .htaccess ?

Comment: Have a look here. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4365129/htaccess-remove-index-php-from-url

Comment: yepper...................

Comment: The problem also here is that I want to show the name of the product instead of index.php?p=544 for example , is it also a mod rewrite ?

Comment: you should rely on your webserver, usually in apache 2.0 I use mod rewrite modifying .htpaccess. have a look at this: http://techie-buzz.com/how-to/create-seo-friendly-urls-using-mod-rewrite-and-php-part-1.html

Comment: I am not getting how to rewrite the url to the new url...

Comment: Why not you refer to the link which marked your question duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12975063/how-to-rewrite-url-in-php

Comment: I tried this                    RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^products/(.+)$ products/index.php?p=$1 [L] but it didn't work